# How to edit Python code to return only the desired answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a complete beginner learning python through an online textbook and this is one of the exercises:

> Write a program to prompt for a file name, and then read through the
>   file and look for lines of the form:
>
> X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475
>
> When you encounter a line that starts with “X-DSPAM-Confidence:” pull
>   apart the line to extract the floating-point number on the line. Count
>   these lines and then compute the total of the spam confidence values
>   from these lines. When you reach the end of the file, print out the
>   average spam confidence.
>
> Enter the file name: mbox.txt
>
> Average spam confidence: 0.894128046745
>
> Enter the file name: mbox-short.txt
>
> Average spam confidence: 0.750718518519

This is the code I've written so far:

```
fname = input('Enter file name: ')

count = 0
total = 0
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
    for line in fhand:
        if line.strip().startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
            count = count + 1
            flt = float(line.split(':')[1])
            total = total + flt
            print(total / count)

except:
    print('Bad file name: ', fname)
```

The output is a long list of numbers, although the final number in the list gives me the correct answer for both 'mbox.txt' and 'mbox-short.txt'. What do I need to change in this code to get it to print only the correct answer?

Comment: If you only want the last item printed, move the `print` to after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only print after your loop is done.

```
fname = input('Enter file name: ')

count = 0
total = 0
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
    for line in fhand:
        if line.strip().startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
            count = count + 1
            flt = float(line.split(':')[1])
            total = total + flt
    print(total / count)

except:
    print('Bad file name: ', fname)
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that.